# In a credit default swap, does the default event have to involve the reference obligation (ie a specific ISIN)

Tags: credit-derivatives

If a company has a default in one of its bonds, but not the reference obligation referenced in the CDS, does that constitute a default?

Also, if there is settlement via physical delivery, does the ref obligation have to be delivered or can another bond be delivered?  Or is physical delivery not done anymore and its just cash settlement?

Answer (score 1):

1 It's quite common for the reference entity (company) to have a default or some other credit event on another debt, which in turn triggers a cross-default on the reference obligation. But if the event does not trigger a cross-default on the reference obligation, then the CDS lives on.

Theoretically, one can default on subordinated debt and not default on senior unsecured, but it would be exremely unlikely (I can think of only one example).

2 Cash settlement is far more common than physical settlement.  The term sheet should have the "Obligations:" section, and "Obligation Category:" is just "bond" or "bond or loan", and "Obligation Characteristics:", something like

Not Domestic Currency

Not Domestic Law

Not Domestic Issuance

Pari Passu Ranking

If physical settlement is chosen, then the protection buyer can deliver to the protection seller anything that satisfies these criteria, i.e. *pari passu* with the reference obligation on the term sheet - can't deliver subordinated if the reference obligation is senior unsecured.